# mysql server install error - mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I try install mysql-server on ubuntu 16.04

```
apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.23-1ubuntu14.04) but 5.7.23-1ubuntu16.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



 apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.



sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

root@ns372228:/home# sudo apt-get remove --purge  mariadb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mariadb
root@ns372228:/home# sudo apt-get remove --purge  mariadb*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-data-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-data' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-common' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-plugin-connect' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-10.1' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-core-10.2' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-connect-engine-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-10.1' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server-10.2' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-plugin-oqgraph' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-plugin-spider' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-plugin-tokudb' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-10.1' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-10.2' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-server' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-10.1' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-10.2' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-test-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-oqgraph-engine-10.0' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-galera-server-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mariadb*'
Note, selecting 'mariadb-plugin-mroonga' for glob 'mariadb*'
Package 'mariadb-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-galera-server-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-connect-engine-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-oqgraph-engine-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-tokudb-engine-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-galera-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-galera-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-test-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-test-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-test-data-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-10.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-10.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-core-10.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-core-10.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-10.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-10.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-core-10.1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-core-10.2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-client-core-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-plugin-connect' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-plugin-mroonga' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-plugin-oqgraph' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-plugin-spider' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-plugin-tokudb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-server-core-10.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-test' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mariadb-test-data' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Still have

```
apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.23-1ubuntu14.04) but 5.7.23-1ubuntu16.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

UPDATE 1

```
This is upgraded system from 14.04 to 16.04 but what i see there is no 14.04 repositories 

apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libmecab2
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
root@ns372228:/tmp# apt update
Get:1 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                                                        
Get:3 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                                      
Hit:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                       
Ign:6 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease                                                                    
Ign:7 http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/1.4/debian stable InRelease                                        
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
Hit:9 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release       
Hit:10 http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/1.4/debian stable Release
Fetched 463 kB in 0s (831 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
W: http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/1.4/debian/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
root@ns372228:/tmp# apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

UPDATE 2
here is available versions mysql

```
 apt search mysql-server
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
auth2db/xenial,xenial 0.2.5-2+dfsg-5ubuntu1 all
  Powerful and eye-candy IDS logger, log viewer and alert generator

mysql-server/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all
  MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)

mysql-server-5.5/now 5.5.60-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]
  (none)

mysql-server-5.6/now 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]
  (none)

mysql-server-5.7/xenial-updates,xenial-security 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
  MySQL database server binaries and system database setup

mysql-server-core-5.7/xenial-updates,xenial-security 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
  MySQL database server binaries
```

Comment: Don't mix repositories. 14.04 vs 16.04.

Comment: This is upgraded system from 14.04 to 16.04 but what i see there is no 14.04 repositories , how check it ?